# How to implement Visual Studio style Add or Remove Buttons toolstrip

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I want to implement visual studio style Add or Remove Ruttons toolstrip like following

[image]

in my winforms application, how can I achieve this?

I haven't tried anything on this as I am not sure how to start and I don't have much working experience on winforms.

Please suggest.

Comment: There's quie a few plugins like [this one](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/ribbonbar.aspx)? which has a lot of predefined stuff (quite useful actually) :) Or [this one](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/D15AE4CD-379A-41A0-BCF8-1013396175CE)

Comment: @jbutler483 This is pretty easy to implement without needing to use third party software.

Comment: @InBetween I was thinking more of styling than implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it doesn't look all that difficult.

Just add a `ToolStripDropDownButton` to your `ToolStrip` with no image or text. That will make the appearance seem more or less similar.

Add to this drop down button one `ToolStripMenuItem` with a "Add or Remove Buttons" caption. We'll call it `AddRemoveMenuItem`.

Now populate `AddRemoveMenuItem`'s child menu items with menu items representing all your configurable `ToolStripItem`s. You can link menu item and configurable tool strip item through the menu item's `Tag` property (you could also subclass `ToolStripMenuItem` adding a `ToolStripItem LinkedToolStripItem { get; set; }` property but I don't think its really worth it).

All these "linked" menu items will have to handle their `Click` events where they will switch their linked tool strip item's `Visible` property and synchronize their `Checked` state accordingly.

I'd do that the following way:

```
 linkedMenuItem.Click += (sender, e) => linkedMenuItem.Checked = !linkedMenuItem.Checked;
 linkedMenuItem.CheckedChanged +=
     (sender, e) =>
     {
         var linkedToolStripItem = linkedMenuItem.Tag as ToolStripItem;

         if (linkedToolStripItem != null)
         {
             linkedToolStripItem.Visible = linkedMenuItem.Checked;
         }
     };
```

When starting up your application set the linked menu items `Checked` state accordingly to your app's default settings, user settings, etc. and you are done.